# bootstrap child menu not align properly

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see the menu image bellow

[image]

i'm using bootstrap navigation menu here .when if its items are few its child pop up menu goes as this .i'm tried a lot but not found a good result ,this menu items generated by dynamically from asp.net

help me to solve this .

Comment: i need to right align child menu with its parent !

Comment: Without any code, no help....

Comment: css code fully mixed with asp.net server side code , that why im stated clearly im used tweeter bootstrap dropdown menu

Comment: Can u create a fiddle or provide the link?

Comment: yes  please just give me time

Comment: please see this http://host.glowbaloutlets.com/